# What is the difference between iterable and enumerable?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, I've heard both the terms "iterable" and "enumerable" used on objects and arrays.

So what is the difference?

Comment: I think they both mean the same thing.

Comment: @epascarello, that is a C# specific question. Note how most of the answers there get C# specific.

Comment: @learner They get C# specific at some point, but by that time, your question is already answered.

Comment: The selected answer is a general definition. *"Iterating means repeating some steps while enumerating means going throug all values in a collection of values."* Iterating a for type of loop. `for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) console.log(arr[i]);`. Enumerating is a for-in type of loop. `for(var prop in obj) console.log(prop, obj[prop]);`.

Comment: @learner: The principle idea behind iteration when compared to enumeration should not change though. The accepted answer on the C# question still would apply I think.

Comment: I'd reopen the question, but... I'll just answer in comment.

Iterable (possibly) should mean entity, which could be iterated on ([see also](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators)), it refers to collection. It is not mentioned in standard, though.

Enumerable means property of object, on which iteration is performed. And it means property, an item of collection ([es-5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/))

Comment: reopen for what? OP got clear explanation in the above comments. right?

Comment: Thinking in terms of interfaces, to me *enumerable* means you can tell how many items the collection has. Meanwhile *iterable* means you can repeat the same action on the elements of a collection, but you do not necessarily know how many there are. But I might be wrong.

Comment: Reopen, beacuse this should not be closed (at least) as duplicate to question in C#.

Comment: Reopen. Anyway...Enumerable is a property with `propertyIsEnumerable` set to `true` [mozilla doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties). You iterate over enumerable properties using `for ... in`. Iterable is a protocol; you loop over an iterable using `for ... of`. You make an object iterable by implementing `@@iterator` [mozilla doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols)